# How to save state before switching to another component in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

For a react component that displays a table with some data I have set up some filters in the state

```
this.state = {
            filters: {
                id: '',
                status: '',
                language: '',
                project: ''
            }
        };
```

If I add a filter the state will be set accordingly

```
   filters: {
                id: '1',
                status: '2',
                language: 'EN',
                project: '101'
            }
```

In this component you can click on a "detail-page" link (it's a simple `<a href>`), so the app switches to another component to show a project in detail. On this detail page there's a back link to switch back to the data table.
My problem is the filters are gone once I switch back. How can the state be persisted, so once I switch back I can show the previously selected filter data? What options are there?

Comment: This problem seem to be the same, so check that solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53699298/reactjs-save-current-state-of-component

Comment: 1. use localStorage, or 2. lift up the state to a component that isn't unmounted when you change the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In reactJS if you will use `<a href="linkOfTheTarget">` then it will re render the whole app despite of rendering the component that is target by you. You can use https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Link for making your app robust. You can use state management like react-redux to store the state regardless of re-rendering of the application. But issue will be with react-redux is that if user will refresh the page the data will be lost. So you can

```
onChange={(e) => { 
             this.setState({filters: {...this.state.filters, language: e.target.value} });
             localStorage.setItem("filteredLang", e.target.value);
}
```